# Upgrading to hibernate 6: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.lock.timeout], use [jakarta.persistence.lock.timeout] instead

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to upgrade to Hibernate 6, but this causes a huge amount of log spam. For every query with my database I get a warning in my console logs:

```
 WARN deprecation:44 - HHH90000021: 
 Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.lock.timeout], use [jakarta.persistence.lock.timeout] instead
```

Our code base does not reference `javax.persistence.lock.timeout` and setting the jakarta property into the peristence.xml file does nothing.

This issue doesn't seem to be documented on the internet, I could only find a single reference to this in a [hibernate bug report](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15189) team, but there are no details.

If its relevant, we are connecting to Postgres on AWS RDS, via the C3P0 connection pool.

This warning continues to appear after removing C3P0 from the server so I don't think this default is coming from there.

Should I just suppress this log source in my log properties file or are there alternatives others are following?

Answer (score 3):

According to [HHH-15768](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15768) it is going to be fixed in Hibernate 6.1.7.

A temporary workaround is to set the property explicitly (accepted modes are defined [here](https://github.com/jakartaee/persistence/blob/master/api/src/main/java/jakarta/persistence/SharedCacheMode.java)):

```
spring.jpa.properties.jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode=ENABLE_SELECTIVE
```

More on the problem and the workaround - [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2717)

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced the same issue. And it seems not to be fixed yet(in 6.0.1).

At least I see in https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/c18e611ed6786fd62a6bf2d17c39589c2452fe35/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/FastSessionServices.java that old (and deprecated) javax.* properties are still set and then logged by LegacySpecHelper:

```
p.putIfAbsent( AvailableSettings.FLUSH_MODE, FlushMode.AUTO.name() );
p.putIfAbsent( JPA_LOCK_SCOPE, PessimisticLockScope.EXTENDED.name() );
p.putIfAbsent( JAKARTA_LOCK_SCOPE, PessimisticLockScope.EXTENDED.name() );
p.putIfAbsent( JPA_LOCK_TIMEOUT, LockOptions.WAIT_FOREVER );
```